# I'm having problems with UUserWidgets on UE5

Tags: c++, linker, unreal-engine5

I'm following a tutorial on user widgets and after I add `TSubclassOf<UUserWidget> widgetClass;` it gives me an error I can't figure it out:

```
MainPlayer.gen.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class UClass * __cdecl Z_Construct_UClass_UUserWidget_NoRegister(void)" (__imp_?Z_Construct_UClass_UUserWidget_NoRegister@@YAPEAVUClass@@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'public: static struct UECodeGen_Private::FClassPropertyParams const Z_Construct_UClass_AMainPlayer_Statics::NewProp_widgetClass''(void)" (??__E?NewProp_widgetClass@Z_Construct_UClass_AMainPlayer_Statics@@2UFClassPropertyParams@UECodeGen_Private@@B@@YAXXZ)"
```

the img:https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKGZO.png

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/SpringArmComponent.h"
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"
#include "MainPlayer.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class SURVIVAL_GAME_API AMainPlayer : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    AMainPlayer();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;


public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;


    

public:

    //Movement and interactions

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category="Camera")
    UCameraComponent* myCamera;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Camera")
    USpringArmComponent* mySprigArm;

    UFUNCTION()
    void moveForward(float value);
    
    UFUNCTION()
    void moveRight(float value);

    UFUNCTION()
    void lookUp(float value);

    UFUNCTION()
    void lookRight(float value);

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Character")
    float movementSpeed;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Character")
    float sensitivity;

    UFUNCTION()
    void interact();

    UFUNCTION()
    void toggleInventory();
    // 

    //Variables

protected:
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Variables")
    TSubclassOf<UUserWidget> widgetClass;

    

    //
};
```

Answer (score 11):

A bit late, but in case you didnt solve it yet...
My guess would be that `UMG` module is not added to `PublicDependencyModuleNames`.

You need to add it in `your_progect_name.build.cs` file:

```
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore"});
```

add the module name to the list, in this case `UMG`:

```
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "UMG"});
```

It should solve the unresolved external issue.

Comment: I'm even later but I do want you to know I hunted for 2 days and this solved it for me. Thank You! :)

Comment: Just wanted to add that this was indeed the solution I was looking for. Was getting the exact same error and this fixed it, thank you so much! Is there a way to know when you need to add a module and where to find a list of pre-defined ones?